# Getting GridView DataKeyNames values when Row_Editing event fires?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

The `DataKeyNames` property in GridViewEmp is composed of 3 fields: *EmpId*, *JobNumber*, *CourseId*. I would like to retrieve the value of *JobNumber*.

So on `GridView.RowEditing`, I tried out the following snippet and I get the value of *EmpId* (the first value of `DataKeyNames`). But I'm not sure how to retrieve *JobNumber* or *CourseId*:

```
protected void EditGridView(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    string empId = GridViewEmp.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

I also need to get the other 2 values, but not sure how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using Values instead of Value like this:

```
string courseId = GridViewEmp.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Values[2].ToString();
```